# Elements with a Div having a specific class name

Tags: javascript, class, html

Hi How can I get hold of elements within a Div that uses a class say "sample"?

There are many Div's in the document

```
<div class="sample"/>
..
<div class="sample"/>
..
<div class="sample"/>
..
<div id = "samplediv">
  <div class="sample">
  <div>
</div>
```

My question was to find the div with class sample and manipulate some properties of this div. So I want to get hold of the Div with class = "sample"?

Comment: Be prepared for about fifty answers saying use jQuery. Also, can you provide a more explicit example of what you want to achieve? Will you be iterating through all of them? A count? What have you already tried that's not working?

Comment: Please find my question updated. I tried $("." + "sample"). It returned an array. since the div has only a class "sample" and not an Id I dont know how to solve this. But all these div's are jqgrid div's that are auto generated.

Comment: Just because it returns an array (actually it returns a wrapper object) does not make it not useful for a single object. Just take the first element or work with the result directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most modern browsers, you can get objects by class name using the function:

```
getElementsByClassName("sample")
```

This is available on any element, including `document` (as in `document.getElementsByClassName`). Problem is, older browsers don't support this. Instead, you can use jQuery to do the same thing:

```
$(".sample")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: SARAVAN: To manipulate one of the elements with the class "sample", you'll simply: `document.getElementsByClassName("sample")[0]` to retrieve the element. So for instance, to set the background to red, you'd `document.getElementsByClassName("sample")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red"`

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery:

```
$('.sample').each(function() { doStuff($(this)); });
```

Or in plain JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('sample');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can just use the equivalent CSS selector, in this case:

```
$(".sample")
```

Answer (score 0):

I voted up drachenstern`s comment so...

if you use Prototype.js you can use function $$(selector) like:

```
$$('#sourceDivId .sample').each(function(elem){ 
// do stuff
});
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

You'd use `document.querySelectorAll("div.sample")`. More [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll). It's supported in IE8 and above, and all modern browsers.

Answer (score -1):

if you can use jQuery you can do this by:

```
jQuery("div.sample");
```

Comment: jQuery("div.sample").each(function(n){
  jQuery(this).property u want to modify for individual array element;
});